# How to access [object Promise] values from fb messenger chat

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access the [object Promise] data from my fb messenger chat bot response. When I send the url to scrape via the chat bot the response comes back [object Promise] how do I resolve this and get access to my data?

The code below is what I have tried but to no avail. The `getProductInfo()` returns the data I need in an object. And `sendText()` function is called in `app.post()` that sends the data to chat bot. What am I missing?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')
const app = express()

const VERIFY_TOKEN = "verify_token";
const ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

var productInfo = {};

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))

// Allows us to process the data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/webhook/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
    }
    res.send("Wrong token")
})

app.post('/webhook/', function(req, res) {
    let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
    for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        let event = messaging_events[i]
        let sender = event.sender.id
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            let url = event.message.text
            let result = getProductInfo(url)
            sendText(sender, "Text echo: " + result)
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

function sendText(sender, text) {
    let messageData = {text: text}
    request({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
        qs : {access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN},
        method: "POST",
        json: {
            recipient: {id: sender},
            message : messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("sending error")
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log("response body error")
        }
    })
}

async function getProductInfo(url) {
    try{
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
            { headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--window-size=1920,1080','--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"'] }
        );
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector('body');
    
        let productTitle = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.querySelector('#productTitle').innerText);
    
        productInfo.title = productTitle;

        return productInfo;
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log('Catch an error: ', error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `let result = await getProductionInfo(url)`? You'd also have to add add `async` in front of your `function` in `app.post('/webhook/'` i believe

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I tried those and did not work